# How do I get the file size in sapui5?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am using File Uploader control in SAPUI5. I want to get the file size once I click on some button. How do I achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller handle the [change](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.unified.FileUploader.html#event:change) event of sap.ui.unified.FileUploader:

```
handleValueChange: function(oEvent){
   var size = oEvent.mParameters.files[0].size;
   alert(size);
}
```

The size you get is in the bytes.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/goxupaluro/1/edit?html,js,output) is jsbin working example.